# creation of DOGGYV5 errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state

Tags: solidity, remix

I need your help guys..
I deployed this contract on Goerli testnet and everything works perfectly fine but when i try to deploy it on ETH mainnet it throws above error.

Please can any guru in the house help me solve this please.
Am using remix for deployment and below is the code am trying to deploy
[image]

Comment: Did you check of the contract size is less than the maximum size?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to deploy to "Remix VM (Shanghai)", not on Mainnet. You need to switch to "Injected Provider" and use metamask.